# A Special Contour Plot with Labels Tangent to Level Curves

Tags: plotting

I would like to produce a contour plot like the one that MATLAB produces. As an example, consider this contour plot from MATLAB. The features which I like about this contour plot are

1- that the labels are tangent to the level curves

2- and they have appeared several times on it.

[image]

In order to have a working example in Mathematica, consider the the following code

```
ContourPlot[(-3600. h^2 + 0.02974 h^4 - 5391.90 s^2 + 0.275 h^2 s^2 + 
  0.125 s^4)/10^7,
 {h, -400, 400}, {s, -300, 300},
 ContourShading -> False,
 BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Cambria", FontSize -> 10},
 ContourLabels -> (Text[#3, {#1, #2}, Background -> White] &),
 PlotRange -> {-1.4*10, 2},
 AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

which produces

[image]

Is there any way to get the two features I mentioned in Mathematica?